# Bash statement hangs when inside here doc

Tags: linux, bash, freeze, heredoc

I am quite STUMPED by why on earth the following bash script would hang in CentOS6.4

```
/bin/cat >> /root/heredoc <<EOF

    if [ $(grep -c "$IP_ADDR\|$HOSTNAME" $HOSTS_FILE) -ne 0 ]; then
EOF
```

Don't worry if the contents of the here doc doesn't make sense. I simply took out the line of code that makes the script hang. I am definitely lacking some insight into how bash handles here docs. It's not the pipe (vertical bar) as it still hangs without the pipe.

Comment: you want the content of heredoc to be executed as script or you just want to have the content as literal string?

Comment: I want the content as a literal string. No processing or evaluation of the content is desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the content as a literal string. No processing or evaluation of
>   the content is desired.

if you want the content as literal text, try this:

```
/bin/cat >> /root/heredoc << 'EOF'

    if [ $(grep -c "$IP_ADDR\|$HOSTNAME" $HOSTS_FILE) -ne 0 ]; then
whatever you have

EOF
```

note, single quoted the heredoc `'EOF'`

here is an example:

```
kent$  cat << eof
$(echo $HOME)
eof
/home/kent

kent$  cat << 'eof'
$(echo $HOME)
eof
$(echo $HOME)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$( grep ... )`. A HERE doc is by default interpreted as double quoted string which means the `grep` is executed. $HOSTS_FILE is probably empty, so grep is waiting for standard input (try pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>).

Comment: if $HOSTS_FILE is empty, you get `grep: (standard input): Input/output error`

Comment: @choroba I am trying to create an upstart conf file from within a script. The grep is within the body of the conf file being generated. How would you do this then?

Comment: @braindead: If you do not want to interpret the heredoc, use `<< 'EOF'`. If you want some variables to be interpreted, backslash the dollar signs you do not want to be interpreted.